# How to modify $(document).ajaxStop function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, monkeypatching

I would like to modify the `$(document).ajaxStop` function to set the `localStorage` variable when it is called (without actually changing the function that it calls). What I have tried is something like this:

```
origstop = $(document).ajaxStop;
$(document).ajaxStop = function(fun) {
        localStorage.var = 'nice';
        origstop(fun);
}
```

This did not work because it changes back right away, so when I run `$(document).ajaxStop` I get the same function as `origstop`.

Another way that I have found on StackOverflow is this:

```
(function($){
    var jqAttr = $.fn.attr;
    $.fn.attr = function( elem, name, value, pass ) {
        if (name === 'ajaxStop') {
            localStorage.var = 'nice';
            jqAttr(elem, name, value, pass);
        } else {
            jqAttr(elem, name, value, pass);
        }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This causes an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')` whenever the function is actually called. Also, I am also not sure how this works, so I have no idea how to fix this either...

What would be the correct way to approach this?